# Error installing npm packages -- node-gyp EOL while scanning string literal common.gypi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm pulling dependencies for React app with `npm i` and I get:

```
gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     options.duplicate_basename_check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 130, in Load
npm ERR!     params['parallel'], params['root_targets'])
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2783, in Load
npm ERR!     variables, includes, depth, check, True)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 399, in LoadTargetBuildFile
npm ERR!     includes, True, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 271, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     aux_data, includes, check)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 308, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict
npm ERR!     LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check),
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/Downloads/offenderbook_web-master/client/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 251, in LoadOneBuildFile
npm ERR!     None)
npm ERR!   File "/home/mark/.node-gyp/20.0.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1
npm ERR!     erate ',
npm ERR!            ^
npm ERR! SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
```

When I looked into the file it literally starts on the 1st line with `erate ',` so I'm not surprised it throws an error. But why and how can I troubleshoot this ?

Do I need newer version of Node ? I've got 20.0 currently installed.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt node-gyp. Try deleting the `node_modules` and `.node-gyp` directories

Comment: The `node_modules` directory isn't created when the process errors out.

Comment: I'll try to nuke `.node-gyp` once again. I've done it before and didn't make much difference.

Comment: Still unsure what's causing the truncation, but I ran into this and ended up replacing the `include` folder in `~/.node-gyp/x.x.x with what I grabbed from the headers URL in the error logs, in my case https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.18.2/node-v18.18.2-headers.tar.gz

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce this problem, but
I can't explain why/how the file gets corrupted like OP described....

**I was able to "fix/workaround"** the problem --  I did what [@jkmartindale suggests in their comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649050/why-im-getting-syntax-error-while-pulling-dependencies#comment136373018_76649050).

Specifically I visited [the nodejs download/release page](https://nodejs.org/download/release/) to find the link corresponding to my current node version  (`node -v`).

At the time I'm writing this, my `node -v` is [version `20.10.0`](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/), so I download its [`node-v20.10.0-headers.tar.gz` file](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/node-v20.10.0-headers.tar.gz) and unzip it to the `node` directory located in `~\.node-gyp\20.10.0\include\node` (for me, that's `C:\Users\there\.node-gyp\20.10.0\include\node`)

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be solved with new versions of node or npm, try downgrading node version to 14.15.x

Comment: I awarded the bounty, this is one valid solution. But I hope others can comment or edit this answer if there are other ways to address it, **without downgrading** . The [Node Release chart](https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases) shows that node version 14 is not supported; as of 1/14/2024 (my post)  version 14 Security support ["Ended 8 months ago
(30 Apr 2023)"](https://endoflife.date/nodejs)  For example, see [@jkmartindale's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649050/error-installing-npm-packages-node-gyp-eol-while-scanning-string-literal-comm#comment136373018_76649050)

Comment: @NateAnderson have you found any other ways? or downgrading is the only option?

Comment: Hi @SwapnilSoni I use the technique from my answer, which is what @jkmartindale suggested in their comments -- that is, I replace the files in `~\.node-gyp\20.10.0\include\node`